# Selenium Webdriver, C# and accessing rows in a table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#

There's been other questions like these, but I feel like I'm missing some of the basics, so I'll try asking a potential duplicate question:

How do I get/list the contents of each row in a table like this?

```
<div class="entity-body list-entity-body entity-content-payload">
   <div class="table-holder l-height-full" style="overflow-y: scroll; flex: 1 1 auto" data-bind="fullHeight: 'leave-space-for-following-elements'">
      <content-placeholder class="l-height-full jsx-component-rendered" content-id="list-page-list">
         <content-placeholder class=" jsx-component-rendered" content-id="standard-list-page-list">
            <section class=" jsx-component-rendered" data-bind="component: { name: listCustomElementName, params: listParams }">
               <table class="table-default" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        ...
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr data-bind="css: { selected: $parent.selected.indexOf(href) != -1 }, loadRelated: $parent.fieldsFromRelated">>
                        <td class="fit-cell-content">
                           <a data-bind="clientHref: href" href="#/Customers/149999/Locations/000" data-server-href="/Api/Customers/149999/Locations/000">
                        </td>
                        <td class="keyColumn fit-cell-content">
                           <a data-bind="clientHref: href" href="#/Customers/149999/Locations/000" data-server-href="/Api/Customers/149999/Locations/000">
                        </td>
                        <td class="keyColumn fit-cell-content">
                           <a data-bind="clientHref: href" href="#/Customers/149999/Locations/000" data-server-href="/Api/Customers/149999/Locations/000">
                        </td>
                        <td class="keyColumn fit-cell-content">
                           <a data-bind="clientHref: href" href="#/Customers/149999/Locations/000" data-server-href="/Api/Customers/149999/Locations/000">
                        </td>
                        <td class="keyColumn fit-cell-content">
                           <a data-bind="clientHref: href" href="#/Customers/149999/Locations/000" data-server-href="/Api/Customers/149999/Locations/000">
                        </td>
                        <td class="fit-cell-content">
                           <a data-bind="clientHref: href" href="#/Customers/149999/Locations/000" data-server-href="/Api/Customers/149999/Locations/000">
                        </td>
                     </tr>
```

There are other things on the page, and this code is nested quite a but down in the tags, but it should be possible. However, one thing is finding the rows and contens (which I need hints for doing) - another is storing it and using it.

UPDATE: kirbycope has a great answer below. Building on that, how do check each row for a specific name and then click it?

UPDATE2: Using kirbycope's examples below, here's what I've got so far:

(I search the table for an row containing a specific text - "Bergen" in a td)

```
var table = GCDriver.Instance.FindElement(By.TagName("table"));
var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

foreach (var row in rows) {
    if (row.Text.Contains("Bergen")) {
    //Console.WriteLine(row.Text);

    var tds = row.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
    foreach (var entry in tds) {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Text);
        entry.Click();
    }
}
```

The Console.WriteLine line works fine, printing this:

```
149999-002
Bergen
0
0
13
Branch Office
```

However, the entry.Click() line does not, resulting in this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference:     
element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520     
(cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Most of what I can find on that exception is that people seem to think it's because an element is not loaded, not accessible etc. on the web page, and to implement a wait or similar. But this is not the case here; I can add a timeout of 10 hours and the exception is still there. Also, if I just use the XPath of a specific row and add .Click() to that, it works fine.

UPDATE 3:
As per ChatuD's help below, I'm trying this to get all the elements of a specific row (tr):

```
var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    foreach (var row in rows) {
        if (row.Text.Contains("Bergen")) {
            IList<IWebElement> List = row.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
            List<String> NewList = new List<String>();

            foreach (var item in List) {
                NewList.Add(item.Text);
            }

            Actions action3 = new Actions(GCDriver.Instance);
            action3.MoveToElement(NewList[<Index number >]).Perform();
        }
```

But - and pardon my lack of both C# and VS knowledge - how do I access the row element in NewList in the last line above? It doesn't work just typing the index number, and "ElementAt" doesn't exist as a method.

Answer (score 10):

Get the table, then its rows, then each row's TDs, then each TD's anchor:

```
var table = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("table"));
var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach (var row in rows)
{
     var rowTds = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
     foreach (var td in rowTds)
     {
         var a = td.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
         Console.WriteLine("HREF: " + a.GetAttribute("href"));
     }
}
```

Or, if you just want each of the TDs anchors you could:

```
var tds = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
foreach (var td in tds)
{
    var a = td.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
    var href = a.GetAttribute("href"));
    if(href.Contains("Customer1234"))
    {
        a.Click();
        break;
    }
}
```

The takeaway here is that *.FindElements() returns a collection of elements that you can parse. In much the same way as document.querySelectorAll() does in JavaScript.

Comment: That simple, eh? :-)

Comment: Hm. What if you wanted to search each row for a specific name and click it? (I notice the contents are links...)

Comment: Yes, or check the td(-s) inside the rows for specific names.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can just grab all TDs or get all rows, then for each row, get its TDs, then for each TD get the Anchor. It all depends on what makes the most sense for you test case.

Comment: The line "var a = td.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));" throws this exception: "threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"a"}"

Comment: And if I try to .Click() the td element(s) (which do have the <a> inside of them), I get this errror: "StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

Comment: The stale element exception is likely thrown after clicking on the first link found. This takes you to a new page where the links no longer exist. Putting them in a List, like @ChathuD provided in his example would do the trick.

Comment: I don't think so, since the exception happens just from this line: "var a = td.FindElement(By.TagName("a"))". This doesn't do any clicking; It just tries to find the element by tagname "a".

Comment: Then the current td doesn't have a child anchor. Wrap it in a try/catch to let the test move on.

Answer (score 2):

As every line start with a `'<a' tag`

```
IList<IWebElement> List = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
List<String> NewList = new List<String>();
foreach (var item in List)
            {
                NewList.Add(item.Text);
            }
```

The you will get all the list of items in the table as NewList.

So for clicking on an element dont directly use `NewList[<Index number>]`.
Use `Actions`.

```
Actions action3 = new Actions(Setup.driver);
            action3.MoveToElement(NewList[<Index number>]).Perform();

            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            action3.Click(NewList[<Index number>]).Perform();
```

Comment: Well, this is basically what I'm doing, and I'm able to find a specific row based on the content of one of the tds. However, when I try CLICKING it (in your example, with item.Click()), I get this error: "OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Which I don't understand, because if I use FirePath to get the XPath for a specific row in the list, I can click it without problems.

Comment: simple matter.I will update my answer

Comment: Hm. What on earth goes into the [<Index number>] space? Nothing I try is accepted...

Comment: index number means the item number of that returning NewList.Just debug the code and see how the NewLine List will looks like after it gose thru the Foreach loop

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions, but I'm very new at both C# and VS. I was thinking to step through the code, but that doesn't seem too easy with a unit test and not an executable project. Anyway, what I don't understand is: NewList.Add(item.Text); <--- here we just add the textual items in the list, right? For the row in question. Then, why shouldn't I be able to do action3.MoveToElement(NewList[0]).Perform(); to access a specific element?

Comment: this is not a silly Question,This is the normal behavior of selenium.Some times selenium web driver can directly access elements which are deep down at a web page,So we are giving little bit push by using actions.

Comment: Yah, I think I get that. But how is the List element accessed?